# How to concatenated all values per ID (Oracle SQL)?

Tags: sql, oracle

FIDDLE: https://dbfiddle.uk/A9gQZtUg

I have table 1,

[image: table 1]

Which has ID, Product, and "UniqueProd# On ID" columns

The "UniqueProd# On ID" shows the count of the unique Products per ID, and it will ignore Products called "Other" when counting.

But I want a "ProductConcat" column, which will Concat all the values of the "Product" column based on the "UniqueProd# On ID column", please see Table 2 example:

[image: table 2]

I was wondering if there was a way to make the concatenated values always go in a specific order? Such as if an ID was has apples, oranges, and bananas, I always want to concatenated value to go by  Bananas, Oranges, Apples in that order.

Comment: [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html)? Based on your fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/bEgaDyZr. The order of values within group can be specified in `within group` clause using general `order by`: any expression that determines ranking of specific value.

Comment: Can u answer this so I can give u best anser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `LISTAGG` function, but without the `ORDER BY` clause being used, the order of the concatenated products is *indeterministic*. So you need to have a column that identifies the order of your products. You could create a table or use a CTE to have your *specific order* then join with your table as the following:

```
WITH products_order(PRODUCT, p_ord) AS
(
  SELECT 'Bananas' AS PRODUCT, 1 AS p_ord FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Oranges' AS PRODUCT, 2 AS p_ord FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apples' AS PRODUCT, 3 AS p_ord FROM dual 
)
SELECT A.ID, A.PRODUCT,
   LISTAGG(DISTINCT CASE WHEN A.PRODUCT <> 'Other' THEN A.PRODUCT END, ', ') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY O.p_ord) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID) AS Product_Concat
FROM Acc A JOIN products_order O
ON A.PRODUCT = O.PRODUCT
ORDER BY A.ID, O.p_ord
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/s2T5ZbOj)